# Como posso resolver isso? Salvar categoria p voltar

Tags: android, firebase

Galera, vou tentar me expressar resumidamente. Tô me aventurando num aplicativo de papel de parede, mas como não tenho muita experiência, não tô conseguindo lidar com esse problema.

Na adapter de download, definir fundo e compartilhar etc... Coloquei p quando o usuário definir/baixa o papel de parede, ele seja transferido p uma activity de um gif animado de 3 segundos.
Nessa activity do gif, coloquei p quando terminasse o tempo, ele fosse transferido de volta p categoria de onde estava.

Nessa tentativa, me esbarrei com um erro fatal:

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main Process: org.serie.wallpaper, PID: 10289
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{org.serie.wallpaper/org.serie.wallpaper.activities.WallpapersActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument
>   'pathString' in child() at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument
>   'pathString' in child() at
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.serie.wallpaper.activities.WallpapersActivity.onCreate(WallpapersActivity.java:75)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

```
package org.serie.wallpaper.activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import org.serie.wallpaper.R;
import org.serie.wallpaper.adapters.WallpapersAdapter;
import org.serie.wallpaper.models.Wallpaper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WallpapersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    List<Wallpaper> wallpaperList;
    List<Wallpaper> favList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    WallpapersAdapter adapter;

    DatabaseReference dbWallpapers, dbFavs;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wallpapers);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String category = intent.getStringExtra("category");

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(category);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new         Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
            }
        });

        favList = new ArrayList<>();
        wallpaperList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new WallpapersAdapter(this, wallpaperList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

            dbWallpapers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images")
                    .child(category);

        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            dbFavs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .child("favourites")
                    .child(category);
            fetchFavWallpapers(category);
        } else {
            fetchWallpapers(category);
        }

    }

    private void fetchFavWallpapers(final String category) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dbFavs.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot wallpaperSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String id = wallpaperSnapshot.getKey();
                        String title = wallpaperSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                        String desc = wallpaperSnapshot.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
                        String url = wallpaperSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);

                        Wallpaper w = new Wallpaper(id, title, desc, url, category);
                        favList.add(w);
                    }
                }
                fetchWallpapers(category);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void fetchWallpapers(final String category) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dbWallpapers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot wallpaperSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String id = wallpaperSnapshot.getKey();
                        String title = wallpaperSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
                        String desc = wallpaperSnapshot.child("desc").getValue(String.class);
                        String url = wallpaperSnapshot.child("url").getValue(String.class);

                        Wallpaper w = new Wallpaper(id, title, desc, url, category);

                        if (isFavourite(w)) {
                            w.isFavourite = true;
                        }

                        wallpaperList.add(w);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private boolean isFavourite(Wallpaper w) {
        for (Wallpaper f : favList) {
            if (f.id.equals(w.id)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

LINHA DO ERRO:

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("images")
 .child(category);
```

Então percebi que preciso definir qual categoria deve ir, se não vai dar 'null'.
P isso, eu preciso salvar qual categoria o usuário estava antes de ser transferido p activity do gif.

Ex como é feito na CategorieAdapter, quando é pego o nome, mas sendo feito quando o usuário clica sobre a categoria.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

            int p = getAdapterPosition();
            Category c = categoryList.get(p);

            Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, WallpapersActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("category", c.name);

            mCtx.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Mas p isso, eu preciso salvar qual categoria estava. 
Como faço isso?

Comment: Experimente substituir a linha `final String category = intent.getStringExtra("category");` por `final String category = intent.getExtras().getString("category");`

Comment: Olá, Rosário.Oobrigado, mas infelizmente não resultou.
O erro persiste!

 .child(category); 

Preciso identificar a categoria antes de start a activity.
No caso, eu preciso salvar a categoria de wallpaper que o usuário estava antes de startar a activity da gif